# how to get last parameter in middleware laravel8

Tags: php, laravel-8

In my laravel8 App,I have routes like this

1. `/home/profile/value`
2. `/home/setting/item/value`
3. `/home/value`
4. `..../value`

I want to check and retrieve last parameter `value` in middleware.
How can I detect last parameter of route in middleware.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get this in your middleware using:

```
$segment = end($request->segments());
```